# Laravel factories not finding database table

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I'm working with Laravel 6.17.1 factories for testing with a very simple model, just one field: 'money' an integer. This is my factory:

```
$factory->define(wallet::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'money' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 500, $max=900)
    ];
});
```

but when I use `vendor/bin/phpunit` to run the tests, I get the next error:

> General error: 1 no such table: wallets (SQL: insert into "wallets" ("money", "updated_at", "created_at") values (545, 2020-03-27 10:20:12, 2020-03-27 10:20:12))

but the table does exist and my model does fit with it, I checked this by creating a function in the controller and creating some data in the table and it works:

```
public function dummyCreation(){
    wallet::create(['money' => 100]);
    return 'works!';
}
```

[image: evidence of model working]

Could someone help me here? I'll add my model and my test below in case it helps:

```
class wallet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['money'];

    public function transfers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transfer');
    }
}
```

```
public function testGetWallet()
{
    $wallet    = factory(Wallet::class     )->create();
    $transfers = factory(Transfer::class, 3)->create([
        'wallet_id' => $wallet->id
    ]);

    $response = $this->json('GET','/api/wallet');

    $response->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJsonStructure([
        'id', 'money', 'transfers' =>[
            '*' =>[
                'id', 'amount', 'description', 'wallet_id'
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->assertCount(3, $response->json()['transfers']);
}
```